# ViewController initialized by xib can not work?

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xib, viewcontroller

This is a weird problem..

1.I create a custom “ view ” by xib, and initialize it by

```
     KWView *oneView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KWView" owner:nil options:nil ]lastObject];
```

This Xib’s File’s Owner name is “NSObject”（then i try any other more,whatever i choose, it runs smoothly）,and there,  i choose  the view’s Custom Class as “KWView”[This xib named "KWView.xib"]

=======  That works !

2.Then i create another custom “viewController” by xib .

```
 KWMenuVC *menuVC = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KWMenuVC" owner:nil options:nil ]lastObject];//  error occurs here
 [self.view addSubview:self.menuVC.view];
```

This Xib’s File’s Owner name is “KWMenuVC”(i also try NSObject), and there,  i choose  the Custom Class of this VC’s view as “UIView”.[This xib named "KWMenuVC.xib"]

=======  This one can not work, it stucks in  “KWMenuVC *menuVC = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"menuVC" owner:nil options:nil ]lastObject]; “  and the error is   “[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view”

3.Later, i try another method to initialize the  KWMenuVC ,which works well how matter how i change its Xib’s File’s Owner name

```
     KWMenuVC *menuVC= [[KWMenuVC  alloc]init]; 
     [self.view addSubview:self.menuVC.view];
```

=======  Works well !

How could this happen??   I used to  construct apps' UI  by codes.  But xib seems more efficient in some cases. Now it seems not a easily understandable stuff.

Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view` suggests that you have a xib which is attempting to bind some view to the `view` property of a `UIViewController` subclass (probably as the File's Owner of that xib). It appears that you are providing a object which is not a `UIViewController` and does not have a `view` property so this binding fails. Without more detail about what bindings these xibs contain or which objects are provided as their owners I can't give a more precise answer.

Comment: Bro,thx a lot for your help.  I utilized the incorrect method..  initWithNibName:bundle:  would be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to initialize a UIViewController with a XIB is:

```
KWMenuVC *viewController = [[KWMenuVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"KWMenuVC" bundle:nil];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: Thx！ I have just tried that,it works!   but how can this line " KWMenuVC *menuVC= [[KWMenuVC  alloc]init]; "also works?   Does it call initWithNibName:bundle: method?

Comment: Now i get it,  UIViewController's  -init method called  initWithNibName:bundle:  if using a xib to initialize it .

Comment: I didn't find any documentation for that, but it could be that if the name of the XIB is equal to the classname, you can skip the nibname. But you easily can test it ;-)